# python: naming a module that has a two-word name

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm trying to put together a really simple module with one .py source file in it, and have already run into a roadblock. I was going to call it `scons-config` but `import scons-config` doesn't work in Python. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711884/python-naming-conventions-for-modules) and looked at [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) but am kind of bewildered, it doesn't talk about two-word-name conventions.

What's the right way to deal with this?

- module name: SconsConfig? scons_config? sconsconfig? scons.config?
- name of the single .py file in it: scons-config.py? scons_config.py?

**edit:** I did see "the use of underscores is discouraged" and that left me at a dead end: should I use "sconsconfig" or "scons_config" (I guess the other ones are out)?

Comment: A single `.py` is a module...

Comment: And a folder is a package, which should be all lowercase without underscores.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If you have to, always use underscores `_`.

Using a dot `.` would not even work, otherwise

```
from scons.config import whatever
```

would break.

But [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) clearly describes it:

> Package and Module Names
>
> Modules should have **short, all-lowercase names**.  *Underscores* **can be used**
>         in the module name if it **improves readability**.  Python **packages** should
>         also have short, all-lowercase names, although the **use of underscores is
>         discouraged**.

**UPDATE:**

To directly target your question: I think `sconsconfig` is fine. It is not too long and quite readable.

But honestly, I don't think anyone will blame you if you use underscores and your code will run with either decision. There is always a certain level where you should not care *that* much anymore.

Comment: I saw "use of underscores is discouraged" and it left me at a dead end.

Comment: @Jason S: Well, use it if readability really suffers or think about another name ;) It is *only* discouraged, not forbidden.

Comment: "There is always a certain level where you should not care that much anymore." True but there are almost always consequences for these kinds of decisions and if you're a beginner like me it's daunting. Thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that the first example - using the dot - isn't terrible. It'd be an example of a namespace package as described in [PEP 420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). It isn't exactly what the author is trying to achieve though with a simple module.

Comment: Example: app_pool VS apppool

Comment: To clarify, underscores are NOT discouraged for python MODULES.  Underscores ARE discouraged for python PACKAGES.

Answer (score 25):

First, the module name is the same as the name of the single .py file.  In Python-speak, a collection of several .py files is a package.

PEP-8 discourages breaking up package names with underscores.  A quick peak at my site-packages directory shows that multiword names are commonly just run together (e.g., setuptools, sqlalchemy)

Module names (that is, file names) may be broken up by underscores (and I usually do this, because I hate namesthatruntogethersoyoucanhardlyreadthem).

Stick with lower-case only (per PEP-8).  This avoids problems when going from case-sensitive to case-insensitive filesystems and vice versa.

Answer (score 11):

Aside from PEP-8, you can also check out how the native Python modules deal with this issue.

If you were to compare [the native modules of Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html) to [that of Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html), you would see that the new tendency with the official devs is to avoid uppercase and underscores. For example, `ConfigParser` in Python 2 becomes `configparser` in Python 3.

Looking at this, the best course of action would be to avoid uppercase and underscores, and just join the words together, i.e. `sconsconfig`.

Answer (score 5):

`-` is a no go. The symbol is used for minus operator. The same is true in most programming languages. Use `_` or otherwise nothing at all.