# Python package naming: verb or noun?

Tags: python, package, naming-conventions

I am writing a Python package that provides a parser for, say, `.xyz` files. I am aware of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), [PEP423](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/), and other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/711884/5433628) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2852283/5433628).

I am hesitating in naming my package `xyzparse` or `xyzparser`.

In other word, **is it better to name a Python package as a noun or as a verb?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use verbs as in `argparse`, `astunparse` and `bisect`. You certainly will find the other opinion, but this makes more sense; you will then define submodules carrying the noun names (e.g. `argparse.ArgumentParser`).

I think there are examples where nouns fit better. I don't think there is a convention for this anyway except that people with [ocd](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=ocd) like me find it difficult not to find a standard for everything :).